# "Metaaccess" of Objects in Java With Variables in the Identifiers

Tags: java, metadata

I want to access to a certain number of objects in Java without write a lot of code, for example:

```
int X;  
for(X=0;X<5;X++){
    jLabelX = /*do something*/
}
```

Would be something like this:

When `X=0` then `jLabel0` is access, `X=1` then `jLabel1` and so on...

Is there any way of doing this? or i need to specify all the cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way of doing this is to *not* have variables called `jLabel0`, `jLabel1` etc in the first place. Instead, have an array variable (or some other collection):

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[5];

for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i] = new JLabel();
    // Whatever
```

You *can* get at fields with reflection, but any time I see variables `x0`, `x1`, `x2` etc I shudder - it's a clear indication that a collection of some kind is a better fit.